# Цикл в bat с проверкой входящих данных

Tags: bat

Как сделать цикл в bat который будет проверять есть ли еще входные данные, 
к примеру for.bat 1 3 тело цикла должно выполниться два раза с данными 1 и потом 3,

```
set i=1
    for %%i%!='' do (
.......
%i% = %i% + 1;
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
@echo off
:cycle
if .%1. == .. goto done
REM требуемые команды с использованием %1
REM например echo Parameter = %1
shift
goto cycle
:done
```

Comment: а как мне дать ему понять что надо уже считывать %2

Comment: что то типа %%i не подоходит

Comment: О том как перейти к %2 и так далее, почитайте `shift`